# How to remove element from list with a corresponding priority queue?

Tags: c++, list, priority-queue

I have a std::list of objects, say rabbits. Each rabbit has two properties: ID and weight. And in this list rabbits are in the order of ID. 
Then I use a std::priority_queue to store pointers to that rabbit list, in the order of weight.

Now I'm going to use this priority_queue to delete the lightest N rabbits in both priority_queue and original list. 
    ***Question*** is: How do I delete in the **original** list?
Sample code:

```
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
list<Rabbit> rabbitArmy; 
priority_queue<Rabbit, vector<Rabbit*>, CompareWeight> rabbitSortByWeight;


for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++) {

    .....

    // each rabbit has different ID and Weight, codes omitted
    Rabbit rabbit(randomID, randomWeight); 
    rabbitArmy.push_back(rabbit);
    rabbitSortByWeight.push(&rabbitArmy.back());
}


// Now I'll delete N lightest rabbits in the priority_queue
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 

    rabbitSortByWeight.pop();
```

What about original list?

By the way, if I have a list, then I want to put it in priority_queue, is there better way than pushing elements one after another?

Comment: You're rabbits are in an object vector, and a pointer priority queue. popping off the pointer from the pqueue is easy (just throw it away). Removing from the *list* is a bit more difficult, since as written it requires a linear search. Have you considered using iterators in your priority queue instead of raw rabbit pointers?

Comment: I don't quite understand how using iterators work...The priority_queue can give me the address of the object in my original that I want to delete, yet there is no way to delete it?

Comment: No worries. It was just a O(1) vs. O(n) deletion optimization. I think junix has a pretty solid answer.

Comment: There is an important issue with your code: You create objects on the stack and push references to them into your list. Unfortunately the objects are removed from stack after leaving the function or the loop. So your code won't shouldn't work anyway I'm afraid...

Comment: @junix this will work fine. the Rabbits he's pushing are *copied* into the `rabbitArmy` container. And he's pulling the address of the last one *from the container* to drop into his pqueue. I don't see an issue with that. His list isn't a list of references (and in fact, no such thing exists in the first place unless wrapped by an idiom called a `ref_wrapper`, a struct/class that contains a reference).

Comment: @Arch1tect Your queue is wrong in decl, btw. The first template parameter should be `const Rabbit*`, as should the template parameter to your container in the queue (the vector).

Comment: I tried remove method, doesn't work... what's the O(1) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the why Arch's code was not *quite* working, and I figure it is probably better to just show it to the OP. The missing link was the *equality* `operator ==()` for removal from the std::list<>. Without that `std::list<T>::remove()` has no way to compare whether the object sent is the one being examined for removal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// my rabbit (I don't have yours).
struct Rabbit
{
    Rabbit(int weight=0, int size=0)
       : weight(weight), size(size) {};

    int weight;
    int size;

    // needed for std::list<>::remove()
    bool operator ==(const Rabbit& other)
    {
        return weight == other.weight
            && size == other.size;
    }
};

// write to output stream
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Rabbit& rabbit)
{
    os << '[' << setw(2) << rabbit.weight << ',' << setw(2) << rabbit.size << ']';
    return os;
}

// functor for comparing two rabbits by address
struct CompareRabbitPtrs
{
    bool operator ()(const Rabbit* left, const Rabbit* right)
    {
        return right->weight < left->weight ||
              (right->weight == left->weight && right->size < left->size);
    }
};

// some typedefs to make life a little easier. first the list
typedef std::list<Rabbit> RabbitList;

// now the priority_queue
typedef std::priority_queue<Rabbit*, std::vector<Rabbit*>, CompareRabbitPtrs> RabbitQueue;

int main()
{
    // seed RNG
    std::srand((unsigned)time(0));

    RabbitList rabbits;
    RabbitQueue rq;

    // load up your rabbits.
    for (int i=1;i<12;++i)
    {
        rabbits.push_back(Rabbit(std::rand() % 10 + 3,std::rand() % 20 + 5));
        rq.push(&rabbits.back());
    }

    // show rabbits
    std::copy(rabbits.begin(), rabbits.end(),
              ostream_iterator<Rabbit>(cout,"\n"));
    cout << endl;

    // remove top N rabbits, in this case 2
    for (int i=0;i<2;++i)
    {
        rabbits.remove(*rq.top());
        rq.pop();
    }

    // show rabbits again.
    std::copy(rabbits.begin(), rabbits.end(),
              ostream_iterator<Rabbit>(cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Run Output**

```
[11,17]
[ 6,17]
[ 8,11]
[12,14]
[ 7, 8]
[ 6,19]
[11,16]
[10,19]
[ 6,21]
[10,14]
[ 7,13]

[11,17]
[ 8,11]
[12,14]
[ 7, 8]
[11,16]
[10,19]
[ 6,21]
[10,14]
[ 7,13]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use the [top](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/top/) method of `std::priority_queue` to get the value of the element about to be popped and use the [remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/) method of std::list?

As example (assuming the queue stores pointers to the elements of the list:

```
myList.remove(*(myQueue.top());
```

or (if the queue is also storing references):

```
myList.remove(myQueue.top());
```

Comment: does this method support object? I tried rabbitArmy.remove(*rabbitSortByWeight.top()) It gives me compile error.

Comment: @Arch1tect firstly: write `rabbitSortByWeight->top()` instead of this dereference and point crap. secondly: What kind of compile error?

Comment: @Arch1tect Well at least my documentation says it does. Would you mind showing the code for this? **Edit**: Reviewing your code I see that rabbitSortByWeight is not a pointer, so rabbitSortByWeight.top() is correct and returns a pointer to the element. I think the problem here is that you are storing references in your list but pointers in your priority queue. Is there a special reason for that?

Comment: I think the list should be the owner of the data. I need to keep both order by ID and by weight. Maybe I don't quite understand your question, what's the proper way?

Comment: @Arch1tect *argh* sorry it's early in the morning for me. If I remeber correct, `*` has precedence over `.`. So `*rabbitSortByWeight.top()` would be the same as `(*rabbitSortByWeight).top()` which is the crap replacable by `->` I meant. But in your case you want to dereference the result of top() so `rabbitArmy.remove(*(rabbitSortByWeight.top()))` (notice the parantheses) should do it.

Comment: @Arch1tect As far as I know there is no difference in "ownership" between pointers and references. The object has to remain in memory as long as references and/or pointers exist to it.

Comment: :P already tried `*(rabbitSortByWeight.top())`  never mind, it's not a urgent problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I would approach this problem.

The example assume a `Rabbit` class with a public `id` member.

**1.** I would just store all my Rabbits in a list, and sort the rabbits *in place*. If the rabbits are in the list in a particular order already - this might be a problem.

```
std::list<Rabbit> l;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    l.push_back(Rabbit(rand() % 10));   

auto comp = [](const Rabbit& a, const Rabbit& b) -> bool{ return a.id > b.id; };
l.sort<decltype(comp)>(comp);

int numToRemove = 3;
for(int i=0; i<numToRemove; i++) l.pop_back();
```

This will remove the 3 rabbits with the lowest ids.

**2.** I would skip the list altogether, and just straight up use the `priority_queue`. This way everything is sorted when you pop the rabbits out. Note that there are other restrictions with the `priority_queue` that may not fit your need.

```
auto comp = [](Rabbit* a, Rabbit* b) { return a->id > b->id; };
std::priority_queue<Rabbit*, std::vector<Rabbit*>, decltype(comp)> q(comp);

for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    q.push_back(new Rabbit(rand() % 10));   

int numToRemove = 3;
for(int i=0; i<numToRemove; i++)
{
    delete q.top();;
    q.pop();
}
```